# Dominant Weight

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I am reading a paper which begin by a reminder about root system associated to a simple lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. let $\mathfrak h\subset \mathfrak g$ a cartan subalgebra.

Question 1: It says that for any dominant weight $\lambda\in\mathfrak h$, we associate a unique up to isomorphism a simple $\mathfrak g-$module, denoted $V_\lambda$ , how to define $V_\lambda$ and why it is unique?

Question 2: it says that $V_\lambda$ contains a highest weight vector, but then evry dominant weight is a highest weight.? is the highest weight unique?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look into an introductory book for the representation theory of semi-simple Lie algebras, for example the book by Humphreys *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*. For (1), note that $\lambda$ need not be dominant in order to have an irreducible heighest weight module associated to it - the property of being dominant shows up when you ask whether these modules are finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you @Hanno; good reference!